# SQLite - problem with "near « ) » : syntax error"

Tags: sql, sqlite, syntax-error

I try here since i didn't find anything anywhere else.
I have a query which has been check by my colleagues and "teachers", but the error remains:

" near « ) » : syntax error".

The (last) query is the following one:

```
WITH valeur_par_ville AS
(
SELECT dep_code, com_code, AVG(valeur_fonciere) as valeur
FROM vente
JOIN bien ON bien.bien_id = vente.bien_id
JOIN commune ON commune.com_id = bien.com_id
WHERE dep_code IN (6,13,33,59,69)
GROUP BY dep_code, com_id
)
SELECT dep_code AS "Département", com_id AS "Commune", round(valeur,1) AS "Prix moyen"
FROM(
SELECT dep_code, com_nom, valeur_fonciere,
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY dep_code ORDER BY valeur_fonciere DESC) AS
rang
FROM valeur_par_ville) AS result
WHERE rang <= 3
```

I hope you can help me on this, because it becomes "black magic" to me!
Thanks.

I tried different ways to reach a result, but the same thing keeps going... I Checked all my data tables, updated SQLite (so PARTITION BY works on it now), reboot, checked the query little by little... No idea where it comes from.

Others colleagues (we are kind of students) managed to have a valid result with their own queries.
But for me:
" near « ) » : syntax error".

Comment: Can you show the whole error? It usually points to the exact part of the code that caused the error.

Comment: Here it is:

[16:20:30] Erreur pendant l’exécution de la requête sur la base de données « Laplace_immo » : near ")": syntax error.

And nothing underligned elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from a different part of the code. I added CREATE TABLE statements to be able to run your code and it's failing differently.

```sql
CREATE TABLE vente(dep_code, com_code, valeur_fonciere, bien_id);
CREATE TABLE bien(bien_id, com_id);
CREATE TABLE commune(com_id);
-- your code here
```

The error:

```
Parse error near line 4: ambiguous column name: com_id
  RE dep_code IN (6,13,33,59,69) GROUP BY dep_code, com_id ) SELECT dep_code AS 
                                      error here ---^
```

After prefixing it with a table name, there's another bunch of errors, e.g.

```
arse error near line 4: no such column: com_nom
  (valeur,1) AS "Prix moyen" FROM( SELECT dep_code, com_nom, valeur_fonciere, ra
                                      error here ---^
```

```
Parse error near line 4: no such column: valeur_fonciere
  ) AS "Prix moyen" FROM( SELECT dep_code, com_nom, valeur_fonciere, rank() OVER
                                      error here ---^
```

etc.

Comment: I modified for no ambiguous column:

WITH valeur_par_ville AS (
SELECT commune.dep_code, commune.com_code, AVG(valeur_fonciere) AS valeur
FROM vente
JOIN bien ON bien.bien_id = vente.bien_id
JOIN commune ON commune.com_id = bien.com_id
WHERE commune.dep_code IN (6,13,33,59,69)
GROUP BY commune.dep_code, commune.com_id
) etc...

The problem still remains...

Comment: @RobinTalbot: Please, post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Apparently, there seems to bo a problem linked to SQLite. I transfered (migrated?) my DB to MySQL and everything worked. So i just can't explain what was the problem exactly. Thanks for trying anyway.